# how to edit htm/css in drupal theme?

Tags: php, drupal, themes

I have a Drupal theme, and I want to edit its HTML/CSS according to my needs. Can anybody tell me how I can change it? (Specific file name?)

I have tried to change page.tpl.php but couldn't get any output.

Answer (score 4):

The file depends on what part of the page you're attempting to update. Here's a great visual of the file structure when it comes to theming: https://drupal.org/node/171194

You'll be editing the html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, and style.css files (or whatever you're calling your main CSS file). Very important - once you make your changes, you need to clear the cache within Drupal so it recognizes the changes. To do this go to "admin/config/development/performance".